# How do I test the speed between my site and a proxy server?

Tags: proxy

I'm getting complaints from employees in the field that our site is slow. When I check it -- the speed is acceptable. They are all going through a proxy server that is not controlled by me.

I'd like to run a continuous ping to the proxy server, but I haven't found anything to do that.

How do I check the speed from my site to a proxy server?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a cronjob to ping a site of your choice, at the frequency you choose. Here I ping google.com every 15 minutes. I can adjust the number of times I ping with the flag `-c` count and the time between pings with `-i` interval. This time is in seconds, I can use shorter intervals if required, for example `0.5`.
I then pipe to `tail -n` to only use the last line with the results. At this stage my output is as follows:

```
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 12.771/17.448/23.203/4.022 ms
```

We then use `awk` to only take the 4th field and use `tr` to replace the slashes with commas. Finally we store the result in a CSV file.
Here is the whole line in `crontab`:.

```
*/15 * * * * ping -c 5 -i 1 google.com | tail -n 1 | awk '{ print $4 }' | tr "/" "," >> /home/john/pingLog.csv
```

It is important to run this as root. To do so we edit the crontab using sudo:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

The end result is a comma separated file that you can open in Excel or equivalent, or process as you wish.
As noted in the ping output the 4 figures are `min/avg/max/mdev`.

Comment: Sorry, I did forget to mention that it should be Windows-based.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version for Windows. The result is not so refined as we had in the Linux version but we're still getting the essentiels. You could put it in a .bat file and run it with a planned task or put it directly in the planned task.

```
ping google.com  | findstr  Minimum >> TotalPings.txt
```

Which adds the following line every time it is run:

```
    Minimum = 23ms, Maximum = 23ms, Moyenne = 23ms
```

You can change the server pinged to suit your needs.